# Multidimensional (4D) array multiplication issue

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

While trying to convert MATLAB code to Python, I am running into a multidimensional (4D) array multiplication issue.

How do I get the same result as MATLAB's using Python/NumPy?

Python 3 NumPy code & result:

```
A = np.arange(1,25).reshape((2, 3, 2, 2))
B = np.array([1,10,100])
A * B[np.newaxis,:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]

array([[[[   1,    2],
         [   3,    4]],
        [[  50,   60],
         [  70,   80]],
        [[ 900, 1000],
         [1100, 1200]]],
       [[[  13,   14],
         [  15,   16]],
        [[ 170,  180],
         [ 190,  200]],
        [[2100, 2200],
         [2300, 2400]]]])
```

MATLAB Code & result:

```
A = reshape(1:24, 2,3,2,2)
B = [1 10 100]
A .* B

ans(:,:,1,1) =
     1    30   500
     2    40   600
ans(:,:,2,1) =
           7          90        1100
           8         100        1200
ans(:,:,1,2) =
          13         150        1700
          14         160        1800
ans(:,:,2,2) =
          19         210        2300
          20         220        2400
```

Comment: NumPy follows row-major. So, the initialization must change too. To have the same format with new row-major ordering, think it would be `A = np.arange(1,25).reshape((2, 2, 3, 2)` and then multiply it with `B[:,np.newaxis]`.

Comment: Comparing the displays is also tricky.  `numpy` shows the last 2 dimensions as blocks.  MATLAB shows the first 2.  In both cases those are the inner most dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

Numpy has row-major indexing as Divakar commented. Furthermore it indexes from `0`.
So you can do as follows:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.arange(1,25).reshape((2, 2, 3, 2))
B = np.array([1,10,100])
ans = A * B[np.newaxis, np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]

ans = np.transpose(ans)

print(ans[:,:,0,0])
print(ans[:,:,1,0])
print(ans[:,:,0,1])
print(ans[:,:,1,1])
```

**Out:**

```
[[  1  30 500]
 [  2  40 600]]
[[   7   90 1100]
 [   8  100 1200]]
[[  13  150 1700]
 [  14  160 1800]]
[[  19  210 2300]
 [  20  220 2400]]
```